# Keccak-256 in PHP

Tags: php, cryptography, sha, keccak

I need to create hashes with **Keccak-256** algorithm (**NOT SHA3**).

I'm running **PHP 7.1**, and when I call to **hash_algos()** returns me the registered algorithms but Keccak-256 doesn't exist.

The supported algorithms are:

```
[0] => md2
[1] => md4
[2] => md5
[3] => sha1
[4] => sha224
[5] => sha256
[6] => sha384
[7] => sha512/224
[8] => sha512/256
[9] => sha512
[10] => sha3-224
[11] => sha3-256
[12] => sha3-384
[13] => sha3-512
[14] => ripemd128
[15] => ripemd160
[16] => ripemd256
[17] => ripemd320
[18] => whirlpool
[19] => tiger128,3
[20] => tiger160,3
[21] => tiger192,3
[22] => tiger128,4
[23] => tiger160,4
[24] => tiger192,4
[25] => snefru
[26] => snefru256
[27] => gost
[28] => gost-crypto
[29] => adler32
[30] => crc32
[31] => crc32b
[32] => fnv132
[33] => fnv1a32
[34] => fnv164
[35] => fnv1a64
[36] => joaat
[37] => haval128,3
[38] => haval160,3
[39] => haval192,3
[40] => haval224,3
[41] => haval256,3
[42] => haval128,4
[43] => haval160,4
[44] => haval192,4
[45] => haval224,4
[46] => haval256,4
[47] => haval128,5
[48] => haval160,5
[49] => haval192,5
[50] => haval224,5
[51] => haval256,5
```

I searched in Google, GITHUB but I didn't found anything, thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't exist. Make it yourself! :-D

Comment: I would like to do it, but my skills are not enough... :-(

Comment: Yikes, Keccak is more complicated than I thought...

Comment: Without ever having touched PHP, i would go for the wrap-somehow-original-c-code approach (which should be possible and saves a lof of implementation headaches).

Comment: Thanks sascha for your tip.

Answer (score 6):

This one worked for me.

https://github.com/kornrunner/php-keccak

```
Keccak::hash('', 256); // 
c5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470
```

It corresponds with the web3.sh3() provided by Ethereum.

```
return [
  ['Hello world!', '0xecd0e108a98e192af1d2c25055f4e3bed784b5c877204e73219a5203251feaab'],
  ["\n", '0x0ef9d8f8804d174666011a394cab7901679a8944d24249fd148a6a36071151f8'],
  ['1', '0xc89efdaa54c0f20c7adf612882df0950f5a951637e0307cdcb4c672f298b8bc6'],
  ['-1', '0x798272c22de7de1bbb41d9d76b5240e67bb83e9ece1afeb940834536b3646693'],
  ['testing', '0x5f16f4c7f149ac4f9510d9cf8cf384038ad348b3bcdc01915f95de12df9d1b02'],
  ['', '0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470'],
];
```